# Prove n-th root is different each other.

Tags: abstract-algebra

1. I already know FTA and I have a question about solving $z^n = re^{ix}$. The candidates for the roots of this equation are $z=r^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{i\frac{2k\pi+x}{n}}$. The number of roots should be below $n$ by FTA, but to verify these candidates are all roots and nothing else can't be, the $z$'s which are depending on $k$ are different each other. I don't know how to prove $z$'s are distinct.
2. Let $n$ is odd and $\zeta_n = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}}$. Surely, $\zeta_n^n$. I wonder $\zeta_n$ cannot be 1 before the power of $n$. That is $\zeta_n^2, \ldots \zeta_n^{n-1}$ cannot be 1. Is it right?. How can we prove it?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- $\;z^n=a \iff p(z)=z^n - a = 0\,$, and if $\,p(z)$ had a multiple root, then that root would have to be a common root with its derivative $p'(x)=n\,z^{n-1}\,$.
- <s>Consider for example the case $\,n=4\,$ with $\,z^4=1\,$, where $\pm 1$ are also roots of $z^2=1$.</s>

---

[ *EDIT* ]  I misread OP's point **2.** as "*if $\zeta_n$ is* ***any*** *$n^{th}$ root of unity, then is it possible that $\zeta_n^k = 1$ for some power $1 \le k \le n-1$ ?*", and the second hint (now crossed out) pointed out that the answer is "*yes*" in general.

However, the question actually being asked was whether this can happen for the particular root $\zeta_n = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}}$. The answer to that is "*no*", which follows from the more general statement that the [primitive roots of unity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/primitive-roots-of-unity/#basic-properties) are those $e^{i \frac{2k\pi}{n}}$ with $\gcd(k,n)=1\,$. Since $\zeta_n$ corresponds to $k=1$ and $\gcd(1,n)=1\,$, $\zeta_n$ is always a primitive root of unity i.e. the lowest power with ${\zeta_n}^m = 1$ is $m=n$.

Comment: I got the answer of the first question. Thanks. However second... Maybe what i wonder is the case when $n$ is odd.

Comment: @cokecokecoke Actually, for all $n$. Misread the 2nd point, sorry, see the new edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually derive (1) from (2), if (2) is proven for *all* n.

Namely, if $z_k=r^{\frac {1}{n}}e^{i\frac {2k\pi+x}{n}}$ then $\frac {z_k}{z_l}=e^{(k-l)\frac {2i\pi}{n}}=\zeta_n^{k-l} $ for $0\le l\le k\lt n $. Thus, it suffices to show that $\zeta_n^k=1$ (where $0\le k\lt n $) only for $k=0$.

To prove (2), note that $\zeta_n^k=\cos\frac {2k\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac {2k\pi}{n} $. The real part must be $1$, and $ \cos\alpha=1$ only for $\alpha=2m\pi $ for some  integer $m $, so it follows that $\frac {k}{n} $ is an integer. This is possible only for $k=0$.